# How to resize a polygon in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm working on my first WPF application and I'm testing out a custom control that is essential a circle with a play button drawn into the middle of it.  I seem to have hit a bit of a hitch though.  When I draw my play button I can't seem to get it to resize alongside the circle.  Specifically, when I resize the circle to be wider or taller, the play button polygon remains the same size and in the same absolute position.  Any pointer on setting up my XAML or code to correct this?

Existing XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WPFTest">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="my:GradientButton">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type my:GradientButton}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Ellipse Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush>
                                            <GradientStop Color="{TemplateBinding GradientStart}" Offset="0"></GradientStop>
                                            <GradientStop Color="{TemplateBinding GradientEnd}" Offset="1"></GradientStop>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                                </Ellipse>
                                <Polygon Points="{TemplateBinding PlayPoints}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <my:GradientButton Content="Button" Height="50" x:Name="gradientButton1" Width="50" GradientStart="#FFCCCCCC" GradientEnd="#FFAAAAAA" PlayPoints="18,12 35,25 18,38" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public class GradientButton : Button
    {
        internal static DependencyProperty GradientStartProperty;
        internal static DependencyProperty GradientEndProperty;
        internal static DependencyProperty PlayPointsProperty;

        static GradientButton()
        {
            GradientStartProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("GradientStart", typeof(Color), typeof(GradientButton));
            GradientEndProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("GradientEnd", typeof(Color), typeof(GradientButton));
            PlayPointsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PlayPoints", typeof(PointCollection), typeof(GradientButton));
        }

        public Color GradientStart
        {
            get { return (Color)base.GetValue(GradientStartProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GradientStartProperty, value); }
        }

        public Color GradientEnd
        {
            get { return (Color)base.GetValue(GradientEndProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GradientEndProperty, value); }
        }

        public PointCollection PlayPoints
        {
            get
            {
                //this is where I'm trying to make the resizing dynamic, but this property never seems to get hit when I put in a breakpoint?
                PointCollection result = new PointCollection();
                double top = this.Width / 2.778;
                double left = this.Width / 4.167;
                double middle = this.Height / 2.00;
                double right = this.Width / 1.429;
                double bottom = this.Height / 1.316;

                result.Add(new Point(left, top));
                result.Add(new Point(right, middle));
                result.Add(new Point(left, bottom));

                return result;
            }
            set { SetValue(PlayPointsProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If all you want is a button showing some fancy graphic, like an arrow in a circle filled with some rainbow colors you do not need to create your own button class. Only do this if you add some new behavior, like tripple click for example. You are better of with just creating a style for this and use the regular button control.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set the Stretch property of the Polygon to Uniform

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to have gotten me part of the way there.  The problem I now face is that my polygon (shaped like a play button) is stretching out over the edges of my ellipse.  I suspect the way to solve this is to create a container of some sort that will have my polygon inside it?  If so, it appears I'm back to square one as I need the container to be dynamically sized to exist (as a square/rectangle) inside my ellipse...

Comment: Just set the Margin on the Polygon to give it some spacing from the outer edge or if you need it to space more dynamically add 3 Row and ColumnDefinitions to the Grid using * sizes to get proportional spacing around the Polygon.

Comment: Thanks, John.  I'll try the row/column idea with the grid.